# Problems with insert a Timestamp

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

I have to insert a link with a sheet with the basic's of my original sheet.

=> At the original sheet there is a `importrange` which insert the data. In the next tab a query take the data - now there should be appear a timestamp when the data in col B (in the Sheet at the link) is updated, but only at the first time the col change from an empty col to a filled col.

I searching at the internet, but I didn't find a helpful answer. On the one hand the most of the Scripts I found didn't work in general or doing a little bit. As a example:

This script worked:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var timezone = "GMT-5";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy";
  var updatedColName = "Bid Responses";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Overview - Working (Hidden)');


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColum();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampCoName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) {
   var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

But the timestamp was not inserted at the row where the col data change, it appear in a completely different row.

Can someone help me to write a Script that do exactly what I want?

Comment: Sorry the link https://docs.google.com/a/unrulymedia.com/spreadsheets/d/1T37zqK4ocRPg_YjPc2ahb_PnLUBxo3Mk8ChJdiTCFj4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you have corrections or additions to your question please edit the question to add them rather than using comments.

Answer (score 0):

Unru,

an onEdit trigger will always require a manual edit to the spreadsheet. In other words: the script runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.A recalculation of a formula does NOT fire an onEdit script.

More info: [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)